# How to apply embedded css in html email?

Tags: html, email

I want to apply embedded css in html email page. But when i am doing this all the css is not applying to html email when trying to send email using this html page. Any solution to enable css visibility in email when send this html page into an email ?

Comment: Is there no way to use all css in head section ?

Comment: Which programming language use for send email?

Comment: All  the email client will support for html include css such as gmail,outlook,thunderbird

Comment: i am using php to send email.

Comment: We can send entire html content using mail function. The receiver will get as we designed

Comment: but only using inline css not embedded. I want using embedded css.

Comment: @UpendraSharma check my answer and review that link I provided. It will show you the issue you might hit with gmail client and stripping the `<style>` tag you are wanting to use.

Comment: I thing you may forget to mention content type on email header

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to `inline` your CSS rather than use the `<style>` tag as it's not heavily supported.

HTML/CSS in email can be a difficult thing due to the fluctuation of support in email clients.

[This list](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) is very helpful for checking out what is supported and help guide you along the way.